# Keeping button on the bottom right corner of a table

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to keep a button in the bottom right corner of a table. How Can I do that ?

```
<HeaderTemplate>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ContentTemplate>
    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td valign="bottom" align="right">
         <asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
   <div>
</ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: What is the issue with your current code? -- http://jsfiddle.net/672oq6yw/

Answer (score 1):

You can add styles to your table cell to align the content to bottom and right:

```
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: right;
```

for an inline test you would have:

```
 <td style="vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right;">
```